# Why is a <td> getting pushed to the right side in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to code a banner in HTML email with a small image on the left and text on the right. The code I currently have looks like this:

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#fcc80d;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-left:30px;">
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;word-break:break-word;">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" style="width:100%;max-width:10%;display:inline-block;">
            <div style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;width:100%;">
              <img src="image.jpg" width="55" height="39" style="height:100%;width:100%;max-width:55px;" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" style="width:100%;max-width:90%;display:inline-block;text-align:left;">
            <div style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;width:100%;">
              LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SET AMET
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I send a test email, the rendering looks off in Outlook - the text is pushed far to the right. I've tried inspecting the code in a browser, but haven't found any reason why the code might be doing that. Any insights would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I am not following the problem.  You say that you want "text on the right", but then you say that the problem is "the text is pushed far to the right".  Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that other people can see the same thing you are seeing, or at least some screenshots or something?  It may also be worth just cleaning up some of your styling; things like `width: 100%; max-width: 10%` are obviously contradictory and are probably not doing you any favors.  Using `inline-block` for table cells is also kind of shady.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. I have removed the style from both the `td`'s and gave the left one a width. The 20px extra width is for the column to have a breathing space before the text.

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#fcc80d;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-left:30px;">
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;word-break:break-word;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" width="75">
            <div style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;width:100%;">
              <img src="image.jpg" width="55" height="39" style="height:100%;width:100%;max-width:55px;" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <div style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;width:100%;">
              LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SET AMET
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```